# React Native outsource function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Consider the following, I have a reusable component, let's call it `myComponent`, `myComponent` is used twice, it also has a prop called whenAccepted where in both places where i use the component i run the same function. I would like to outsource that into a new file so I can just import it and run it instead of writing it twice. Any advice for that? I was thinking about HOC's but i'm not sure if it would work as i'll need more stuff, for the function to run it also needs some data present in the both files where I use it. How would you go about that Reactors?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, by "I run the same function. I would like to outsource that into a new file" you want to extract a function to be used in multiple components. Here's how I'd accomplish that.

#### Simplified project structure:

```
./mySharedFunction.js
./MyComponent.js
./MyComponent2.js
```

#### Create the function to be used in multiple components

```
// mySharedFunction.js

export default const mySharedFunction = (data) => {
 ...do stuff...
}
```

#### Import function and use it in the constructor.

```
// MyComponent.js

import mySharedFunction from './mySharedFunction.js

export default class MyComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    mySharedFunction(data)
  }

  ...some code...

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

#### Import function and use it in a class method.

```
// MyComponent2.js

import mySharedFunction from './mySharedFunction.js

export default class MyComponent2 extends Component {

  ...some code...

  classMethod = (data) => {
    mySharedFunction(data)
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I will need to pass the function as a prop to another component like ```<myComponent whenAccepted={theFunctionINeed} />```

Comment: Then you could just do `<myComponent whenAccepted={mySharedFunction} />`